# How can I install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS 32 bit? (GUI ISO found; see added ref)

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, 32-bit

How can I install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS 32 bit Desktop?
I understand that 18.04 was the last version to support 32 bit, but at https://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04.5/ I only see 64 bit versions.

Comment: Ubuntu Desktop 17.10 & later was only available for *amd64*, not *i386* so you need to install Ubuntu Server 18.04, use the netboot i386 ISO (then add `ubuntu-desktop`), upgrade from an earlier release, or use a *flavor* of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Desktop.  Two *flavors* went beyond 18.04 as well; and i386 upgrades were possible until *disco* or 19.04 reached EOL (as Lubuntu & Xubuntu offered i386 ISOs into the *alpha* stage of *disco* or 19.04; so if those were used; upgrades on packages were available until 19.04 reached EOL).

Comment: FYI:  I used pentium M, pentium D & pentium M i386 machines to QA-test i386 releases up to 19.04, but the last was 18.04.5 & I'd for sure not want to use Ubuntu Desktop on any of them...  The last Ubuntu Desktop I booted on a pentium 4 for example was 16.04 & it was SLOW! and thus **not fun** so I sure didn't try and slower pentium M boxes, nor went later. But Lubuntu, even Xubuntu was great on those boxes (Lubuntu was great up to 19.04 where Xubuntu was slowing as it continued it's port to GTK3).

Comment: @brewmanz What CPU model do you have? If you can please run `lscpu | grep name` on target hardware and show us the output.

Answer (score 5):

i386 ISOs are available, however the last Ubuntu Desktop ISO for i386 was for Ubuntu 17.04.

eg.  https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/bionic/

where you'll note a

```
i386 - For 32-bit Intel/AMD (x86)
```

There were just fewer options, namely no Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Desktop ISO.

Flavors too offered 18.04 i386 ISOs; however *flavors* only come with 3 years of support, thus they are now no longer fully supported.

Lubuntu & Xubuntu provided i386 ISOs for 18.10, and in fact further (into the *disco* or 19.04 cycle, but both dropped i386 prior to 19.04's release).

Comment: I'll admit now the question is closed; I still have Lubuntu 18.04 LTS running on a thinkpad t43 (i386 only laptop; it's not the only i386 device I still use).  Given my usage of that device, I'm not worried about the EOL 18.04 *flavor*; if I was I'd switch to Debian as I used that device for pre-release testing of Debian 10/Buster & 11/Bullseye and know they'll run (*a little slower maybe*); but for my use of it - currently it doesn't warrant a change.  My other i386 used devices do use Debian.

Answer (score 3):

Although Ubuntu does not have a 32 bit ISO for version 18.04, you can use 32 bit ISOs for Ubuntu flavors like [Ubuntu MATE](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-mate/releases/18.04.5/release/), [Xubuntu](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/18.04.5/release/) or [Lubuntu](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/18.04.5/release/).

If you need to use the GNOME desktop (Ubuntu's default desktop interface), you can later on install it with

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

But if you have an old PC (which is likely, due to the 32 bit processor), I would suggest you to stick with Lubuntu or Xubuntu.

Alternatively, switch to [Debian](http://debian.org/), which does not plan to drop 32 bit support anytime soon, and it is very similar to Ubuntu.

Comment: 18.04 flavors are EoL.

Comment: @ChanganAuto They are supported on [this site](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19616/how-long-do-we-support-ubuntu-flavors). Practically, there is no difference between Xubuntu LTS and Ubuntu + XFCE. They would continue to get the same updates. (*I deleted my comment by mistake, and again added it*).

Comment: It was just a statement of fact, also corroborated by the other answer. The inferences are all on your own. That said, the best service we can bring for this kind of questions is to point out that currently there AREN'T good alternative within the Ubuntu family. Users should be directed to one of the (rapidly dwindling) handful of distros that still support 32-bit. (re-added to preserve the logical order)